# Image can't be loaded Angular 2

Tags: html, typescript, angular, nativescript

I followed this [doc](https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/image) but the image doesn't show up on the UI. I need to use checkbox and I read that it should be done with the help of image. So my checkbox image doesn't appear. Where am I doing wrong?

```
import {Component, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import {NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from 'nativescript-angular/router';
import {APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "../app.routes"
import ImageModule = require("ui/image");
var ImageSourceModule = require("image-source");

var image = new ImageModule.Image();
image.imageSource = ImageSourceModule.fromResource("checkbox_checked");
//image.imageSource = ImageSourceModule.fromResource("checkbox_unchecked");

@Component({
selector: "checkbox",
properties: ['checked : checked'],
events: ['tap'],
template: `
<StackLayout backgroundColor="#b3d9ff" width="300" height="550">

  <Label style="font-size : 20px" text="Choose contacts to sync"></Label>
    <Image
      [src]="checked ? 'res://checkbox_checked' : 'res://checkbox_unchecked'"
      class="checkbox"
      (tap)="onTap()"
      dock="left">
    </Image>
</StackLayout> `
})

 export class SyncComponent{
 public tap: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
 public checked: boolean = false;

 constructor() { }

 public onTap(): void {
     this.tap.next(this.checked);
 }
}
```

[image: here is the screenshot of the UI]

Comment: `properties:` should be `inputs:` and `events:` should be `output:`. `properties` and `events` are deprecated since a long time.

Comment: Thank u very much. I'm quite new to angular. 
I have replaced them, but still no change. Is there anything that I'm still missing?

Comment: I didn't expect this to solve your problem. I don't know NativeScript. The `res://...` URL looks weird to me but might be NS specific

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you are reading NativeScript core part of the documentation, however there is Angular part, where have been described the specifics for NativeScript Angular2 project. you could read more about the images [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/ui-images.html). In regard to your question you could use in your NS Angular project this `<Image src="{{checked ? 'res://icon' : ''}}"></Image>` kind of syntax, to bind the image src property for your scenario.

app.component.html

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label text="Tap the button" class="title"></Label>
    <Image src="{{checked ? 'res://icon' : ''}}"></Image>

    <Button text="TAP" (tap)="onTap()"></Button>

    <Label [text]="message" class="message" textWrap="true"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent {
    public counter: number = 16;
    public checked:boolean=false;

    public get message(): string {
        if (this.counter > 0) {
            return this.counter + " taps left";
        } else {
            return "Hoorraaay! \nYou are ready to start building!";
        }
    }

    public onTap() {
        this.counter--;
    }
}
```